# Google Calendar API - Error 401 Login Required

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

I'm using the Google Calendar API to add events, and am getting the 401 error that states "Login Required".

I tested it offline first using wamp/localhost and it worked fine in a simple php file, but once I moved it to a live server (which uses wordpress, so I built it into an admin plugin to test) it stopped working. I can still get the access token (and refresh token), but it keeps giving the error.

I've put the Auth token into the header, and all the code works offline.

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the headers weren't being sent correctly for some reason.

I ended up attaching the access_token to the url (apparently this can be done as noted under the Calling a Google API section here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer), and the request starting sending back errors about being unable to understand form encoded data.

This was happening even though I was specifying the content-type as application/json in the header.

**Solution**: I moved the code over to curl and it worked instantly. It seems like file_get_contents can be a bit finicky, so if you're having this issue give curl a shot.

Hope it helps!